# Is there a way to not include methods when converting an object to a json?

Tags: javascript, json

Right now, I'm trying to convert a object to a json, but the object has methods in it.

One common solution I've found is storing the function in the json, but that wouldn't work for me (mainly because that would totally break updating)

I think it will be easier to reinitialize the function every time the program is reloaded. What would be the best way to exclude functions when stringifying to json, but including the functions when the json is parsed?

**Extra note**: some of the functions are stored in arrays and other objects

**Edit:**
Current code to load json data:

```js
var loadData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("slotAuto"));
G = {
    ...G,
    ...loadData
};
```

Current code to save json data:

```js
var toSave = JSON.stringify(G, G.ReplaceNull);
console.log(toSave);
window.localStorage.setItem("saveGame", toSave);
```

Replace Null function:

```js
if (value == null) {
    return undefined;
};
return value
```

Example object:

```js
{
    functionList: [function () {
        console.log("do something")
    }]
}
```

Example output:

```json
{
    "functionList": [null]
}
```

Comment: you can do this with some additional args passed to `.parse`

Comment: Can you add relevant code for your question.  Pls refer to this post on how to ask proper question so that you get answers and not get question closed. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Anil_M what code would I include?

Comment: *Is there a way to not include methods when converting an object to a json?* - [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) doesn't include methods: **`undefined`, Functions, and Symbols are not valid JSON values. If any such values are encountered during conversion they are either omitted (when found in an object) or changed to null (when found in an array)**.

Comment: If you end up with JSON-s containing methods, you are not using `JSON.stringify()`, and then the question leaves a bit too much for imagination.

Comment: @tevemadar they get changed to null, which I don't want because that breaks parsing the json

Comment: @picPuppy613 full code (if u can) else, part of code that will help us reproduce the problem / understand the problem.

Comment: code or you will not get help without explaining that help  you need, that's how SO works.

Comment: @flakerimi added code

Comment: Please show a brief example of an object with functions that is serialized to JSON with null as the value.

Comment: @HereticMonkey `"broadcastDirectory":{"ccBegin":[null,null],"ccEnd":[null,null],"ccVersion":[null],"bmSettlementName":[null],"bmConfirmAscend":[null],"bmCheatColonists":[null],"bmCheatMorale":[null],"bmCheatHealth":[null]}`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the original object with functions and the JSON that results. Note that what you've shown would be the result of properties which are arrays of functions, which is certainly possible, but odd given the names.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I specify in the original question that some of the functions are stored in arrays or other objects

Comment: Fair enough. You can still [edit] your question to include the original object *and* the serialized JSON.